# Select date from calendar then display results from a field range within date selected

Tags: php, mysql

In my table `main_stock` I have a field `newown` where the input can be either **New Purchase** or **Existing Product**.

I want to create a report of all the New Purchase in field `newown` from a day that has been selected -

Firstly I have a page which they can select the date from a calendar `curr_timestamp field` and click submit.

When they submit the date I need this to be carried onto a php page `newpurchase_report.php` and display all New Purchases that have been added on that day, any help would be fantastic?

Thank You

This is currently my newpurchases_report.php:

```
<?php
    // connect to the database 

$host = '...'; 
$username = '...'; 
$pass = '....'; 

mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass); 
mysql_select_db("stock"); 
$curr_timestamp = $_GET['curr_timestamp'];
$thenumber = 1;  
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM main_stock WHERE curr_timestamp='$curr_timestamp' ORDER BY newown ASC ") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
print "<table border cellpadding=1 width=95%>";
print "<span style='font-size: 22px;background-color : #ffff00;'>New Purchases</span>"; 
print "<tr>";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>Number</span></td> ";  
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>Data</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>Master Category</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>Category</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>Product Description</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>New or Exsisting?/span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>Barcode</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>Serial No.</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color :  #ffff00;'>Stockcode</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>Status</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;background-color : #ffff00;'>Hiretrack</span></td> ";
print "</tr> ";

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 

print "<tr> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>". $thenumber++;"</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['curr_timestamp'] ."</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['mastercategory'] ."</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['category'] ."</span></td> "; 
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['product_desc'] ."</span></td> ";
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['newown'] ."</span></td> "; 
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['barcode'] ."</span></td> "; 
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['serial'] ."</span></td> "; 
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['stockcode'] ."</span></td> "; 
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['status'] ."</span></td> "; 
print "<td><span style='font-size: 12px;'>".$info['hiretrack'] ."</span></td> "; 
print "</tr> ";

} 

print "</table> ";



// disconnect from the database 

mysql_close();

?>
```

Im not sure whether it is this page that needs editing or my index page (where you select the date from the calendar)?

Comment: What do your form and form handler look like?

Comment: we need to see your form data, how the said calendar input field looks and especially the `<form>` element with attributes

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting to newpurchase_report.php firstly `var_dump($_POST)` within newpurchase_report.php to check the values are being posted to the page. Then if they are you can run a query against your db using the `$_POST['timestamp']` as the where date added is equal to the date posted.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but thought I would offer the simple solution if what I take it you are doing is in fact what you are trying to do.

Comment: I do sincerely hope you're escaping POST data before using it in your database queries…

Comment: was merely giving the solution to finding the date that they want to use in the db. realized how is it phrased sounds like i am suggesting to use the POST where I just mean that is where the value you need is found

Comment: The timestamp does carry across to newpurchase_report.php I just need to code that displays all the new purchases from the date selected ? (Sorry i'm new to this)

Comment: If you have already got the select statement in place I guess it would be something like this:
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($db_result)){
//do the outputs of $row here
}

Comment: I have attached a copy of my newpurchase_report.php. I'm not sure whether its this that needs editing or my index.html page (where the date will be selected)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php this may help you find out where you're going wrong. hope this helps